# Is that Possible To Add List<item> value from different Script File Unity C#

Tags: c#, list, class, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have a simple questions.

I have two file script :

1. Player.cs

   ```
   using UnityEngine;
   using System.Collections;
   using System.Collections.Generic;

   public class player {
       public List<item> itemx = new List<item> (); // Here


   }
   ```
2. File Inventory.cs

   ```
           using UnityEngine;
           using System.Collections;
           using System.Collections.Generic;
           using UnityEngine.UI;

           public class inventory : MonoBehaviour {
               public player playerx;

               itemDatabase database;

               // Use this for initialization
               void Start () {

                   database = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("itemDatabase").GetComponent<itemDatabase> ();
                   //Generate the Slot and Slot Name;
                   for(int i = 1; i <= 24; i++) {
                       playerx.itemx.Add(new item()); // Here

                       playerx.itemx[i] = database.items[i]; // And Here

                   }
               }
           }
   ```

As you can see in player.cs file i have declare a list variable :

```
public List<item> itemx = new List<item> (); // Here
```

and in Inventory.cs file i want to add the value using :

```
playerx.itemx.Add(new item()); And Here
```

is that possible to save the value variable to player.cs file ?

Thanks

Comment: You need to the instance of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## NOTE

in your question, you have

```
   public class Player
```

instead of

```
   public class Player:MonoBehaviour
```

I assume that's just a typo.  If you're trying to have a "free" class Player (as in an OO environment), you can't do that.

---

Correct, there is absolutely on problem with doing this!

A couple of things...

Note that in the second script it would be:

```
 public player playerx; ... WRONG

 public Player player; ... CORRECT
```

and then just

```
player.items.Add( .. etc )
```

(Don't forget that of course you must drag to connect the "Player player" inspector variable. If you do not know how to do that say so and I will give you a link to a tutorial.)

Secondly, in the first script you have a problem.

There's a stupid thing in Unity where "public" means "inspector variable"

In fact you want an "ordinary" public variable as in any ordinary programming language, strangely enough you have to type this

## "[System.NonSerialized] public"

it's just one of those weird things about Unity. In fact in many projects you never use inspector variables.  So you just constantly type "[System.NonSerialized] public" everywhere.  The long one "[System.NonSerialized] public" is sort of the "normal" one if you see what I mean.  Use it all the time.  Only when you especially want an inspector variable, use "public".

```
  public List<item> itemx...   WRONG

  [System.NonSerialized] public List<item> items...   CORRECT
```

Comment: Or use Properties. Important though: he needs a reference to the player. Since it doesn't derive from MonoBehaviour, he needs `player = new Player()` somewhere and initializing the list in a constructor might also be a good idea.

Comment: AH!  I just assumed it was a MonoBehaviour.  recall he can't even use inspector variables or whatever if it is not a Unity component.

Answer (score 0):

How about this. Assuming database object returns [items] or something.

```
                database = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag 

("itemDatabase").GetComponent<itemDatabase> ();
                    //Generate the Slot and Slot Name;
                    forach(item _item in database.items)
    {
 playerx.itemx.add(_item);
}
```

if your database returns something different you can try

```
playerx.itemx.add(new item
{
itemproperty1 = _item.property1, 
and so on.
};
```